# How can i pass a param in the axios.get function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I've tried to pass a prop through a component. It works but I can't put the value in the URL of axios.get. 
I have the same code in the other Component, and it works there.
Hope somebody can help me.

```
interface VideoProps {
    videoId: number
}

interface CommentState {
    comments: any,
    videoId: number
}

export default class ShowComments extends React.Component<VideoProps, CommentState>
{
constructor(props: CommentState) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        comments: [],
        videoId: this.props.videoId,
    };
}

componentWillMount(): void {
    const videoId = this.props.videoId;
    axios.get('/api/get/comments/'+ videoId)
        .then((response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
            this.setState({
                comments: response.data
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but in general it's recommended to do async stuff in `cDM` (not `cWM`).

Comment: Do you get the correct value from the props?

Comment: I get the correct value, yes

Comment: Make sure you're running the code you think you are. This is how you do it, so if it's not working, something else is at play, or the error isn't actually occurring here. For example, the request will finish after the initial render; do you handle that case?

Answer (score 0):

```
    axios.get(`/api/get/comments/${videoId}`, {
      params: {
        param1: 'param1',
      }
    })
    .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({
            comments: response.data
        });
    });
```

Also, this won't work:

```
this.state = {
    comments: [],
    videoId: this.props.videoId,
};
```

`this.props` should be undefined in the constructor, use `props.videoId`, not sure if this may cause an error.

Comment: Although OP does state "It works but I can't put the value in the URL of `axios.get`". (Which means he uses the phrase "it works" differently than I do.)

Comment: Yo, i mean get the right value of videoId, but i can't pass it in the url

Comment: Thanks for the attention on this problem. I'm in the beginnig of programming, i'm sorry. I just want to added the value to the url to get the right route